# JSON Encode specific datatypes

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP Array which looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [label] => Standard Stop
        [code] => 5
        [excludeIF] => [miniTrack, isTriangleHanger, tubeTrack, boxTrack]
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => Soft Stop With Lag
        [code] => 7
        [excludeIF] => [miniTrack, isTriangleHanger, tubeTrack, boxTrack]
    )
```

When I do a json_encode it generates something like this:

`{"label":"Standard Stop","code":"5","excludeIF":"[miniTrack, isTriangleHanger, tubeTrack, boxTrack]"}`

The problem with that encode is that it's making the `code` a string and it's also making the `excludeIF` a string.

`code` needs to be a float

`excludeIF` needs to be an array

Is something like that possible with JSON Encode?

Comment: Cast the code to a float before passing to json_encode()?

Comment: `excludeIF` *is* a string, but you could convert it to an array with explode()